# Counting the size of sets of permutations having k cycles

Tags: combinatorics, symmetry

I'm trying to teach myself combinatorics from Bender and Williamson's *Foundations of Combinatorics with Applications* (2006). Without an instructor to assist I am at times stymied by the perceived terseness. The following contains excerpts from the chapter section on Burnside's Lemma.

Background: The first part of the chapter section discusses permutation functions *g* ∈ *G*. Burnside's Lemma is then introduced. I begin to get a bit lost, however, when the gamma function is introduced:

*Instead of looking at permutations...we can look at the way the permutation rearranges the positions of the sequence. For example g<sub>2</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>x<sub>3</sub>x<sub>4</sub>x<sub>5</sub>x<sub>6</sub>) = x<sub>3</sub>x<sub>4</sub>x<sub>5</sub>x<sub>6</sub>x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub> can be interpreted as saying position 1 is replaced by position 3, position 2 is replaced by position 4, and so forth... To emphasize both the difference and the relationship, we use **γ**... In cycle form γ<sub>2</sub> = (1,3,5)(2,4,6).*

The gamma function is then spelled out a bit more formally.

***Principle:** In the set of allowed functions, N(γ) counts precisely those allowed functions which are constant on the cycles of γ; i.e. those functions **f** such that f(x) = f(y) whenever x and y are in the same cycle γ.*

Here comes the actual problem:

*How many ways can 4 identical round green beads and 4 identical round red beads be arranged to form a necklace of 8 beads?...
Obviously all that matters for counting purposes is the size of the cycles--not what they contain. Altogether there are 16 permutations of 8, which are shown here in 5 classes, where P<sub>k</sub> is the set of permutations having k cycles...*

*P<sub>8</sub> (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)*

*P<sub>5</sub> (1)(2,8)(3,7)(4,6)(5), (1,3)(2)(4,8)(5,7)(6), (1,5)(2,4)(3)(6,8)(7), (1,7)(2,6)(3,5)(4)(8)*

*P<sub>4</sub> (1,5)(2,6)(3,7)(4,8), (1,2)(3,8)(4,7)(5,6), (1,4)(2,3)(5,8)(6,7), (1,6)(2,5)(3,4)(7,8), (1,8)(2,7)(3,6)(4,5)*

*P<sub>2</sub> (1,3,5,7)(2,4,6,8), (1,7,5,3)(2,8,6,4)*

*P<sub>1</sub> (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), (1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6), (1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2), (1,6,3,8,5,2,7,4)*

My Questions:

**1.** I don't immediately see how one gets 16 permutations on the set {1,2,...,8}. Is there a way to count the size of and/or enumerate the elements in each P<sub>k</sub> other than tedious inspection?

**2.** Remind me, what exactly is the difference between permutation (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8) and permutation (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)?

**3.** Why are there no P<sub>3</sub>, P<sub>6</sub>, or P<sub>7</sub>? Why can't (1,3,5)(2,4,6)(7,8) be a permutation? Is there a way to determine that other than inspection?

**4.** What precisely does it mean for a function to "be constant on the cycles of γ"?

If I take the above for granted I can mostly follow the rest of the argument. To be clear, this is not homework, so I would really appreciate as much detail as possible. Yes, I have read and done many of the problems in previous chapters, but I'm stumbling on this point nonetheless. Reviewing other bread-counting questions has so far not proved too helpful.

Thank you for any clarification.

[Note: Apologies for some of formatting. Not sure why it won't allow me to have whitespace in a comma-delimited list]

Comment: This article will help you find your answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: I'm aware of multi-choosing, but I fail to see the connection. Also, the wikipedia articles makes no mention of cycles.

Comment: Your post is a tough block of text. I still do not grasp what does word "cycles" mean in this context.  :-/

Comment: It's a superficially different approach, but see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics). The so-called Necklace Formula there, which counts precisely what you're interested in, is an application of the (beautiful) Polya's Enumeration Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the chapter, here's my take on it. Recall the setup, we consider strings of length 8, composed of four 0's and four 1's, for example 00001111 or 01101001, which is the set $\{0,1\}^8$. Now, we consider equivalence classes on these strings to obtain the necklaces.

1. The eight strings $00001111, 10000111,11000011,11100001,\dots,00111100,00011110$ all represent the same necklace, we only start to read at different positions. But at each of these eight positions we may also read from right to left, that's the flipping part. So, in total we get $8\cdot 2=16$ permutations. I don't know any better way to obtain the number of elements in $P_k$.
2. The [cyclic permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Definition) can be understood as a shorthand notation.  To understand $\gamma=(146)(253)$, you can start by writing down
   $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2& 3& 4&5&6\\\,\end{pmatrix},$$
   so just the integers appearing in $\gamma$ (no matter where) in increasing order in the first row, leaving the second row blank. Next, we look at the first cycle $(146)$. This means that we map $1$ to $4$, which we map to $6$, which we map to $1$ (since it is a cycle). In the matrix this amounts to
   $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2& 3& 4&5&6\\4&&&6&&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
   The second cycle $(253)$ means that we map $2$ to $5$ to $3$ to $2$, yielding
   $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2& 3& 4&5&6\\4&5&2&6&3&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
   This matrix written as a map $g$ would be $g(1)=4$, $g(2)=5$, $g(3)=2$, $g(4)=6$, $g(5)=3$, $g(6)=1$.
   Applying this to $(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)$ gives $1$ to $1$, $2$ to $2$,...,$8$ to $8$ (we only close the cycles), which is the identity. On the other hand, the cycle $(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)$ gives $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $4$,...,$7$ to $8$, $8$ to $1$, which is
   $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2& 3& 4&5&6&7&8\\2&3&4&5&6&7&8&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
3. We will have to write the $16$ permutations down, and then translate them into cyclic permutations. The shifts are
   \begin{align*}
   g_0&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_1&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   2&3&4&5&6&7&8&1
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_2&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   3&4&5&6&7&8&1&2
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_3&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   4&5&6&7&8&1&2&3
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_4&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   5&6&7&8&1&2&3&4
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_5&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   6&7&8&1&2&3&4&5
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_6&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   7&8&1&2&3&4&5&6
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_7&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   8&1&2&3&4&5&6&7
   \end{pmatrix}.
   \end{align*}
   The shifts with negative orientation are
   \begin{align*}
   g_{-0}&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   1&8&7&6&5&4&3&2
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_{-1}&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   2&1&8&7&6&5&4&3
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_{-2}&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   3&2&1&8&7&6&5&4
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_{-3}&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   4&3&2&1&8&7&6&5
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_{-4}&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   5&4&3&2&1&8&7&6
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_{-5}&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   6&5&4&3&2&1&8&7
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_{-6}&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   7&6&5&4&3&2&1&8
   \end{pmatrix},\\
   g_{-7}&=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
   8&7&6&5&4&3&2&1
   \end{pmatrix}.
   \end{align*}
   This yields the cyclic permutations. We denote the number of cycles with $k$, to indicate which $P_k$ the cyclic permutation belongs to:
   \begin{align*}
   \gamma_0&=(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8),k=8,\\
   \gamma_1&=(12345678),k=1,\\
   \gamma_2&=(1357)(2468),k=2,\\
   \gamma_3&=(14725836),k=1,\\
   \gamma_4&=(15)(26)(37)(48),k=4,\\
   \gamma_5&=(16385274),k=1,\\
   \gamma_6&=(1753)(2864),k=2,\\
   \gamma_7&=(18765432),k=1,\\
   \gamma_{-0}&=(1)(28)(37)(46)(5),k=5,\\
   \gamma_{-1}&=(12)(38)(47)(56),k=4,\\
   \gamma_{-2}&=(13)(2)(48)(57)(6),k=5,\\
   \gamma_{-3}&=(14)(23)(58)(67),k=4,\\
   \gamma_{-4}&=(15)(24)(3)(68)(7),k=5,\\
   \gamma_{-5}&=(16)(25)(34)(78),k=4,\\
   \gamma_{-6}&=(17)(26)(35)(4)(8),k=5,\\
   \gamma_{-7}&=(18)(27)(36)(45),k=4.
   \end{align*}
   Now, it should be clear why $P_3$, $P_6$, $P_7$ are missing.
4. A function $f:\{1,\dots,6\}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ is constant on the cycles of $\gamma=(146)(253)$ if $f(1)=f(4)=f(6)$ and $f(2)=f(5)=f(3)$. Let $g$ be the permutation corresponding to $\gamma$, as in Item 2. Notice that we have $f\circ g=f$, where $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$ is the composition. In the example with the necklaces we have to pay attention since we need to have exactly $4$ zeros and $4$ ones. So, we have $N(g_0)=\binom{8}{4}$ since we can choose $4$ position for the zeros to obtain a function $f$ (which doesn't have to be constant anywhere because all cycles have length $1$). A more interesting example is $N(\gamma_{-2})=\binom{3}{2}+\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}=6$, where we can either choose two out of the three cycles of length two (yielding four positions in total) to equip with the zeros, or we choose one out of three cycles of length two and both cycles of length one (four positions in total) for the zeros. The remainder follows analogously.

**Equivalences**: Here's a picture to illustrate the 16 permutations. The upper half shows a possible necklace, then we flip it upside down, displayed in the lower half, still the same necklace. Both in the upper half and in the lower half we obtain the string from the necklace by choosing a starting point and writing down the eight colors. Each of the resulting strings represents this same necklace, as explained under Item 1.

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

**Equivalence Classes**: For completeness, here are all $8$ possible necklaces. Mathematically, these are [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class#Definition_and_notation), that is, sets of strings that result in the same necklace.
Notice that in the sets below, I have listed some elements multiple times. The reason is that the sets are all constructed in the same manner, by applying the permutations $g_0,g_7,\dots,g_1,g_{-0},g_{-7},\dots,g_{-1}$, which explains why, there are listed $16$ elements in each set (counting each ocurence of each element). Say, we consider the equivalence class $[00101011]$. The string $00101011$ corresponds to a function $f(1)=0$, $f(2)=0$, $f(3)=1$, $f(4)=0$, $f(5)=1$, $f(6)=0$, $f(7)=1$, $f(8)=1$. The set is constructed as follows. First, we take $f\circ g_0$, meaning $(f\circ g_0)(1)=f(g_0(1))=f(1)$, $(f\circ g_0)(2)=f(g_0(2))=f(2)$,...,$(f\circ g_0)(8)=f(g_0(8))=f(8)$, so $f\circ g_0=f$, which corresponds to the same string, the first element in the set. The second element is obtained from $f\circ g_7$, that is $(f\circ g_7)(1)=f(g_7(1))=f(8)=1$, $(f\circ g_7)(2)=f(g_7(2))=f(1)=0$, $(f\circ g_7)(3)=f(g_7(3))=f(2)=0$, $(f\circ g_7)(4)=f(g_7(4))=f(3)=1$, $(f\circ g_7)(5)=f(g_7(5))=f(4)=0$, $(f\circ g_7)(6)=f(g_7(6))=f(5)=1$, $(f\circ g_7)(7)=f(g_7(7))=f(6)=0$, $(f\circ g_7)(8)=f(g_7(8))=f(7)=1$, so the element is $10010101$. The other elements are computed analogously. If you remove all duplicate entries in the sets, then you will get $8$ equivalence classes, which are the sets and represent the necklaces, with a total of $70$ elements, which are the strings.
\begin{align*}
[00001111]&=\{00001111,10000111,11000011,11100001,11110000,01111000,00111100,00011110,\\
&\phantom{=\{}01111000,11110000,11100001,11000011,10000111,00001111,00011110,00111100\},\\
[00010111]&=\{00010111,10001011,11000101,11100010,01110001,10111000,01011100,00101110,\\
&\phantom{=\{}
01110100,11101000,11010001,10100011,01000111,10001110,00011101,00111010\},\\
[00011011]&=\{
00011011,10001101,11000110,01100011,10110001,11011000,01101100,00110110,\\
&\phantom{=\{}
01101100,11011000,10110001,01100011,11000110,10001101,00011011,00110110\},\\
[00011101]&=[00010111],\\
[00011110]&=[00001111]\quad\textrm{(I will skip duplicates now)},\\
[00100111]&=\{
00100111,10010011,11001001,11100100,01110010,00111001,10011100,01001110,\\
&\phantom{=\{}
01110010,11100100,11001001,10010011,00100111,01001110,10011100,00111001\},\\
[00101011]&=\{
00101011,10010101,11001010,01100101,10110010,01011001,10101100,01010110,\\
&\phantom{=\{}
01101010,11010100,10101001,01010011,10100110,01001101,10011010,00110101\},\\
[00101101]&=\{
00101101,10010110,01001011,10100101,11010010,01101001,10110100,01011010,\\
&\phantom{=\{}
01011010,10110100,01101001,11010010,10100101,01001011,10010110,00101101\},\\
[00110011]&=\{
00110011,10011001,11001100,01100110,00110011,10011001,11001100,01100110,\\
&\phantom{=\{}
01100110,11001100,10011001,00110011,01100110,11001100,10011001,00110011\},\\
[01010101]&=\{
01010101,10101010,01010101,10101010,01010101,10101010,01010101,10101010,\\
&\phantom{=\{}
01010101,10101010,01010101,10101010,01010101,10101010,01010101,10101010\},\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. This is the sort of explanation I was hoping for. The only portion I'm a bit unsure of is the second block of 8 cycle permutations listed: generally speaking, how would you define what it means to be "negatively oriented"?

Comment: On some occasions, there exists a reasonable definition of orientation: for example triangles, where we usually order the corners counterclockwise, same for angles, base vectors in the coordinate system, and in this case, taking the necklace to be the unit circle centered at the origin in $\mathbb R^2$, you would typically start at $(1,0)$ and move counterclockwise on the circle. Negative orientation means moving clockwise.

Comment: One final question if you don't mind. On rereading I realize that the calculation of 16 permutations still does not entirely make sense to me. You say that for any of the 8 permutations (obtained by shifting to the right) we could just as well read from the other direction. Therefore we have 8 * 2 = 16. But isn't that double counting? Isn't any additional permutation obtained by reading from the opposite direction just going to repeat one of the original 8 permutations? If not, could you list all 16 so I can convince myself? Thank you.

Comment: Of course, here it doesn't matter what we choose to be the positive and the negative orientation. What matters, is the insight that flipping the necklace upside down gives us additional patterns. We can also think about it this way: Imagine that you want to manufacture a necklace. So, you take a thread and spread it out from left to right. Then you start to pull the beads on the thread, until all eight beads are on the thread, aligned from left to right. Then you tie the ends of the thread together to complete the necklace.

Comment: The 16 permutations are $g_0$ to $g_7$ and $g_{-0}$ to $g_{-7}$. They are all different.

Comment: I thought the original value of 16 was obtained by counting how many ways you could shift the example string 00001111. The first 8 permutations map to the following, right?

00001111
00011110
00111100
01111000
11110000
11100001
11000011
10000111

Now, looking at g−0, the first permutation in the second block of 8, it would also map to 01111000, no? But we already included that above. So multiplying by 2 just seems like double counting. But I guess I need to image the string laid out in a circle. So multiplying by two is the flipping of the necklace?

Comment: Also, what justifies picking the necklace 00001111 in order to compute the 16 permutations? Why not 10101010 instead?

Comment: It does not matter if we take $00001111$ or $10101010$, because we do *not* count the number of strings that map to the same necklace, but the number of possible permutations of any string that results in the same necklace. For both strings and any other string, if you decide to start reading at position 4 from left ro right (corresponding to $g_3$), you will obtain the same necklace, and if you start reading at position $4$ from right to left (that's $g_{-3}$), you will also obtain the same necklace.

Comment: Looking at the picture, I understand that there are 8 rotational permutations we could take the necklace through, and for each rotation we could flip it to get another permutation. Therefore, 8 * 2 = 16 permutations. What I still struggle with is why that isn't double counting since every permutation realized by flipping is an ordering that would appear in one of the original 8 rotational permutations. I'll have to study the cycles in more depth to gain the correct intuition I suppose. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Now, I completely wrote down all equivalence classes ($=$necklaces) and explained how to obtain them. I hope it helps to clarify the different notions and their relations.

Comment: Nice! I'll go through it with a fine-tooth comb, so to speak.

Comment: If you have questions, feel free to ask. The double counting you are referring to is the repeated appearance of an element in the equivalence class. However, looking at the 16 permutations $g_0,\dots,g_7,g_{-0},\dots,g_{-7}$ directly (the 16 matrices), you will see that they are all distinct. And this is the group $G=\{g_0,\dots,g_7,g_{-0},\dots,g_{-7}\}$ in the lemma, with $|G|=16$.

Comment: I went through your solution again, played with it a bit, and now I think I got it. By focusing purely on the numbered *positions*, the uniqueness of the 16 permutations leapt out at me. (Number 8 points on a circle 1-8.  There are 8 permutations by rotation. Return to the original numbering and "flip" from left to right. Now repeat the rotations. These 8 additional permutations are entirely unique to each other and the original 8. So we have 16 in total.) It was the fact that many of said permutations repeat the same *string* that was throwing me I think. Thanks!

Comment: That sounds exactly right, great!